# Wrong output on simple python program

Tags: python

I'm a beginner at python and I'm working on while & for loops. I've created a program that should print out distance traveled and time.

The code I created is:

```
speed = int(input('what is the speed of the vehicle in mph?')) 
time = int(input('How many hours has it traveled'))
print('Hour\tDistance Traveled')
print("------------------")

for distance in range(l,time):
    distance = speed * time
    10
    print((time+1),"\t", (distance))
```

It gives me the wrong output:

```
6     480
6     480
```

Instead of my desired output:

```
1    80
2    160
```

I tried putting different increments or adding a variable for the increment on the range function.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the `for` loop.

Comment: Neither `speed` nor `time` change in the loop, so why do you expect `speed * time` to change? You're using `distance` as the iteration variable, but then reassigning it.

Comment: What is `timep`? Where do you assign `l`? Is that supposed to be the number `1`?

Comment: See [formatting code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

First, the range function should have the starting point as 1 instead of 'l'. Most likely this is a typo. This seems to be causing a syntax error. So change range(l, time) to range(1, time+1).

Second, inside that for loop of yours, you're for some reason assigning a new value to the distance variable and this is overwriting the loop variable and causing the same distance value to be printed multiple times. You'll need to use a different variable for the distance.

Here is some updated code that works as expected:

```
speed = int(input('What is the speed of the vehicle in mph?'))
time = int(input('How many hours has it traveled?'))

print('Hour\tDistance Traveled')
print("------------------")

for hour in range(1, time+1):
    distance = speed * hour
    print(hour, "\t", distance)
```